# Installation of a DER certificate in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, openssl, certificate, der

I'm having issues trying to automatically install a DER certificate with Chrome. The error reported back is `Error 502 (net::ERR_NO_PRIVATE_KEY_FOR_CERT)`.

After doing some research, `openssl` doesn't support DER files with private keys and Chrome only accepts DER certificates. I'm thinking that there may be a specific MIME type that needs to be returned possibly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MIME type being returned was incorrect; it needs to be returned as `application/x-x509-ca-cert`.